# Why Does My Deploy Directory Keep Changing

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Sorry if this is a really dumb question,  I am just starting out with AWS.

I am using ElasticBeanstalk to deploy a Django app.

The first time I deployed the code the path to the code was `/var/app/staging` later I noticed it had changed to `/var/app/current`. It seems to changes back and forth after some but not all deploys.

How can I either programmatically determine the path or make it be the same path every time?

As you can imagine, this situation makes running manage commands impossible if your don't know that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you **can't change** that behavior as this is integral to how EB works.

`/var/app/current` stores currently running (i.e. live) application version, while `/var/app/staging` is for storing new version just before EB will make it current one.

> How can I either programmatically determine the path or make it be the same path every time?

Yes, sort of. In `.ebextentions` you have one specially relevant section which enable you to run your **management commands**:

- [Container commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands): Container commands are run from the **staging directory**, where your source code is extracted prior to being deployed to the application server.

Subsequently, the commands which you run in `Container commands` will be executed in `/var/app/staging`. Also when you run your management commands in `Container commands` you know exactly where your application files are.